# Substitute based on regex

Tags: r, regex, string, regex-lookarounds

relatively new to R, need help with applying a regex-based substitution.
I have a data frame in one column of which I have a sequence of digits (my values of interest) followed by a string of all sorts of characters.
Example:

```
4623(randomcharacters)
```

I need to remove everything after the initial digits to continue working with the values. My idea was to use gsub to remove the non-digit characters by positive lookbehind.
The code I have is:

```
sub_function <- function() {
  gsub("?<=[[:digit:]].", " ", fixed = T)
}


data_frame$`x` <- data_known$`x` %>% 
  sapply(sub_function)
```

But I then get the error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (X[[i]])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The function has no arguments, then `gsub` is substituting but from what? In your code, there is no `x` in `gsub("?<=[[:digit:]].", " ", x, fixed = T)`. Also, why the pipe? I would do `sub_function(data_known$x)` after redefining the function `sub_function <- function(x)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a base R function.
It uses `sub`, not `gsub`, since there will be only one substitution. And there's no need for look behind, the meta-character `^` marks the beginning of the string, followed by an optional minus sign, followed by at least one digit. Everything else is discarded.

```
sub_function <- function(x){
  sub("(^-*[[:digit:]]+).*", "\\1", x)
}

data <- data.frame(x = c("4623(randomcharacters)", "-4623(randomcharacters)"))

sub_function(data$x)
#[1] "4623"  "-4623"
```

---

### Edit

With this simple modification the function returns a numeric vector.

```
sub_function <- function(x){
  y <- sub("(^-*[[:digit:]]+).*", "\\1", x)
  as.numeric(y)
}
```

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you!
If there are negative values as well, can I just add a second function with a "minus" in the front of the regex?

Comment: @Nuramon Glad it helped. One more thing, when you say you want to *"continue working with the values"*, does that mean you want the function's output to be numbers, not character strings?

Comment: I just convert them to numeric after the function, so I did not even think of the function itself doing that, but thanks for your concern.

Comment: @Nuramon It might make the code after the function clearer to have `y <- sub(.)` and then return `as.numeric(y)` in the function. All taken care of in one function call. I will edit with this version.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to accomplish this, but I like using functions from `{tidyverse}`:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create some dummy data
df <- tibble(targetcol = c("4658(randomcharacters)", "5847(randomcharacters)", "4958(randomcharacters)"))

df <- mutate(df, just_digits = str_extract(targetcol, pattern = "^[[:digit:]]+"))
```

Output (contents of `df`):

```
  targetcol              just_digits
  <chr>                  <chr>      
1 4658(randomcharacters) 4658       
2 5847(randomcharacters) 5847       
3 4958(randomcharacters) 4958
```

Answer (score 2):

If you always want to extract numbers from the data, you can use `parse_number` from `readr`. It will also return data in numeric form by default.

Using @Rory S' data.

```
sub_function <- function(x) {
  readr::parse_number(x)
}

sub_function(df$targetcol)
#[1] 4658 5847 4958
```